# parsing html with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm parsing html with DOMDocument in php.

I found I'm unable to select all  using an xpath query. However the getElementsByTagName() method works fine.

Here is the code:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load("file.html");
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$links = $xpath->query("//a");
$links2 = $xml->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach($links as $link){
    echo "<br>$k: ".$link->nodeValue; // this doesn't print the node value. $links is empty
}
foreach($links2 as $link){
    echo "<br>$k: ".$link->nodeValue; // this prints OK the node value
}
```

I'd have thought xpath->query("//a") would be the same as getElementsByTagname("a") but apparently isn't.

Could anybody tell me why they aren't the same. Or if they are, what am I doing wrong to select the  nodes using the xpath query?

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce. It gave me the hint I need it. My problem was when loading the file. I need to load using `$xml->loadHTMLfile('file.html')` and not the `load()` method.

Comment: Gordon, for some reason I don't see a link to mark your comment as an answer

Comment: moved my comments to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce: http://codepad.org/N8BlsQro

If you want to use `load` or `loadXML` your markup has to be valid X(HT)ML. HTML is SGML based. Try with `loadHTML` or `loadHTMLFile`.

Note that when you use `loadHTML` or `loadHTMLFile`, DOM will try to repair any invalid HTML to an extent that it is workable for DOM. For instance, it will add a basic HTML skeleton around any partial HTML documents and that can have an effect on your XPath queries (not in the case of `\\a` though).

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$links = $xpath->query('//a/@href');
```

Comment: OP isnt looking to get the href attribute

Comment: He already stated //a did'nt work for him, so was suggesting an alternative.

Comment: If `//a` doesnt give any results, why should `//a/@href` give any results?

Comment: I use it, but only to retrieve links from <a> tags so thought it might help strangely enough... or are we not meant to suggest things that have worked for us in the past? :) Oh, some of us actually work and do this while doing other things so don't have time to reproduce the code from every question... seemingly you have a lot of time on your hands :)

Comment: @Brian well, the thing is that using `@href` picks from the attribute axis of the a elements. But if the XPath doesnt return any a elements in the first place, trying to get from the attribute axis cannot work. So it's a somewhat odd suggestion to try. It's like saying: go through the door and sit on the chair, when there is no door.