# how to convert html files in to text/string format including tags in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to represent  tags with content inside Html file .
I have multiple files having ts ,css formatand html format.
I want to convert all the html files in to text format .so that i can read the tags inside the html file.

Comment: html is essentially a text file - PHP can read and process an html perfectly well - take a look at parsing html with `DOMDocument`

Comment: can u just show me the simple code ,because i am new to this PHP,so i face these types of issues

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php/3577662

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730555/parsing-html-with-domdocument

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571232/parse-html-with-phps-html-domdocument

Answer (score 0):

Just change the extension to .txt and open it in the browser. Then you can see all the source in text strings on the browser window.

Comment: Changing the file extension is a bad advice. Any file can be opened with any text editor without changing its extension.